# ie9/CSS: Flyout menu not working in ie9, but looks great in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Please see this flyout menu: http://www.caseen.com/store.html. It looks amazing in both Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE9! Trying to see what is going on =(.

It looks like ie9 is completing ignoring the stylesheet, but in error checking and clicking ie9 direct mode, it shows up however VERY ugly with huge nasty white borders around the links!

Please see my code:

```
<div class="flyout">
                          <ul>
                            <!--START: CATEGORIES-->
                            <!--START: CATEGORY_FORMAT-->
                            <li><a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID">&nbsp;CATEGORY</a>
                            <!--END: CATEGORY_FORMAT-->
                                <ul><!--START: SUB_CATEGORY_FORMAT-->
                                    <li><a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID">&nbsp;CATEGORY</a></li>
                          <!--END: SUB_CATEGORY_FORMAT--></ul>
                          <!--END: CATEGORIES-->
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          </div>
```

AND CSS

```
.flyout {
width: 130px;
height: auto;
position:relative;
margin: -10 0;
padding: 0;
z-index:10000;
}

.flyout ul li a {
display:block; 
text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
width: 130px;
border: solid;
border-color: #000;
border-width: 0 0 0 5px;
text-align:left;  
font-size:12px;
line-height: 25px;
}

.flyout ul { 
padding:0px;
list-style-type: none;
}
.flyout ul li {
float:left; 
margin-right:1px; 
position:relative;
}
.flyout ul li ul {
display: none;
}

.flyout ul li:hover a {
border: solid;
border-color: #fff;
border-width: 0 2 0 5px;
color: #60dfe5;
}

.flyout ul li:hover ul {
display:block; position:absolute; top:0;
left:130px; 
width:10px;
}
.flyout ul li:hover ul li a.hide {
background:#000; 
color:#fff;
}

.flyout ul li:hover ul li:hover a.hide {width:180px;}
.flyout ul li:hover ul li ul {display: none;}
.flyout ul li:hover ul li a {
display:block;
background:#000; 
color:#60dfe5;
width:200px;
}
.flyout ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IE9 is defaulting to quirks mode on your site, so there is likely something wrong with your markup, either the doctype, or general structure.

Take a look at this validation report:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.caseen.com%2Fstore.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

You have a number of unclosed tags and other major issues. IE is probably choking on these and causing quirks mode. First I'd recommend cleaning up your markup to eliminate that possibility. It should really happen regardless.

Comment: The CMS supplied with a older style template... I'll see what I can do thanks. Still looks like IE9 hates borders on hovers and things like that =(

Answer (score 1):

Your DOCTYPE declaration is wrong, it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Though i'd suggest HTML5s DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```